# KVM switch changes resolution

Tags: windows-7, display, kvm-switch

I have 3 computers hooked up to a 4-port KVM switch and I am having a problem with the resolution on one of my computers. Whenever I switch to another computer and come back, the resolution goes from 1440 x 900 (where I set it) to 1024 x 768. The other two computers stay at whatever resolution I set them to, but the one computer just keeps going back to 1024 x 768. I have had the KVM switch for almost two months now and I have not had this problem before. The computer that is having the problem is a new build, but I have had it for about a week and it only starting exhibiting this problem today. I frequently switch back and forth between computers, and 1024 x 768 looks terrible. Does anyone know how I could fix this?

Additional details:

- Computer 1: Windows 7 x64, Intel Core
  i5-2500k, Resolution 1440 x 900 (This
  is the problem computer)
- Computer 2:
  Windows 7 x86, Intel Celeron 430,
  Resolution 1280 x 1024
- Computer 3:
  Windows 7 x86, Intel Core 2 Duo
  E4300, Resolution 1440 x 900

Computer 1 uses the on-die graphics from the 2500-k and computers 2 and 3 use the integrated video from the motherboard.

On a different forum someone told me I needed to disable the autodetect function and sent me a link to a question (on this forum).  I tried all the potential fixes (could only do one because the rest didn't apply or were not possible in windows 7) but nothing worked.  The one I tried was to disable TTM in the registry by changing the value data of "UselViewHelper" under the "Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\TMM" key to "1", but it didn't work.  Is there a way to disable the autodetect in Windows 7?